# Compile-time weaving causing unnecessary error/exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm new in using spring boot

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to log the execution of a method (elapsed time and result) using aop.

I can use spring-aop just fine, the problems comes when the aop cannot capture the internal method call (`private` method) and the method call from `new` object.

After browsing through many references, it looks like I should use compile-time weaving (since I have the source code with me)

my pom.xml looks like this

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn clean package`, it shows the advice for the `private` method and the method from `new` object was being weaved, and the project was compiled successfully.

But when I start the .jar file and execute the API using Postman, it shows exception error that not occured before I was adding this compile-time weaving such as:

`feign.codec.DecodeException: Type definition error: [simple type, class someClass]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException`

`nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!`

How do I achieve this compile-time weaving without causing unnecessary exception when I run the program? because it was just fine when I remove the build plugin for compile-time weaving

Any response would be appreciated

**P.S:**

I have tried using spring-aop with self-injection using `@Autowired` but it causing NPE when the internal method trying to execute `.saveAll()` from `@Autowired` repository and I don't know how to fix that so I choose this compile-time weaving

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should make your problem reproducible, otherwise probably nobody can help you. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A GitHub project would be appreciated. Thank you.